# scrapy xpath selector returning empty array

Tags: python, arrays, scrapy

This response.xpath statement is returning an empty array and I'm not too sure why. I'm trying to retrieve @alt result. This is what I have tried...

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="all_teams_war_images"]/div/a/img/@alt').extract()
```

Oddly enough this returns all elements within that div

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="all_teams_war_images"]').extract()
```

this is the website I am trying to scrape https://baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.shtml

Comment: I believe `'//*[@id="all_teams_war_images"]/div/a/img/@alt'` is looking only in the first child `<div>` underneath the element with that id, which does not contain any `<a>` elements.  How did you get that xpath?  Did you type it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you're trying to parse is hided in HTML comment section. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731288/scrapy-not-finding-table-css) for details